# JSON breaking: using coldfusion regex to remove some quotes and double quotes

Tags: regex, json, coldfusion

i am going nuts here, trying to remove some quotes and double quotes in my json response,

there are some characters too like period, comma etc, i am trying like this

```
<cfset mystring = rereplace(mystring, '(['""])', '\\\1', 'all') />
```

but unable to fix it, please guide me thanks

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: Also, what is the result of the code? An error? How does the result differ from what you expected?

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Comment: What does the initial string look like? Is it a valid JSON string?

Comment: It would be better if you can provide the json example that you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're enclosing your regex pattern string in single quotes, but then escaping the double quote inside that string, but not the single quote. You might try the following:

```
<cfset mystring = rereplace(mystring, "(['""])", "\\\1", "all") />
```

But I'm not sure that will actually do what you want. That will also escape double and single quotes where they don't need to be escaped -- such as the quotes surrounding names and values. For example, the JSON

```
[{"name":"value"}]
```

would become

```
[{\"name\":\"value\"}]
```

Surely that isn't what you want! Rather, you would need to determine where double quotes fall within strings surrounded by double quotes, and escape those (assuming they're not already escaped). I am not certain that ColdFusion regex, or any regex flavor, is up to that task. Rather, whatever service is producing the invalid JSON needs to be fixed.